# EXTJS show/ hide many containers in controller

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have a view that has many containers in ExtJs. Consider the items of the view are something like the following.

```
    initComponent : function(){
    this.items = [{
                        xtype  : 'button',
                        text   : 'menu1',
                        itemId : 'btnMenu1'
                    },{
                        xtype  : 'button',
                        text   : 'menu2',
                       itemId  : 'btnMenu2'
                    },{
                        xtype  : 'button',
                        text   : 'menu3',
                        itemId : 'btnMenu3'
                    },{
          xtype  : 'container', 
          itemId : 'report1', 
          items  : [{
            xtype : 'button',
            title : 'clickme 1'
          }]        
        },{
          xtype  : 'container',
          itemId : 'report2', 
          items  : [{
            xtype : 'button',
            title : 'clickme 2'     
          }]                
        },{
          xtype  : 'container',
          itemId : 'report3',
          items  : [{
            xtype : 'button',
            title : 'clickme 3'             
              }]
        }]
   this.callParent();
   }
```

Then in mycontroller I want to hide and show the containers according to the button I click.
In the controller I have the refs and selectors for these containers,

```
       refs     : [{
                    /***all containers**/
        ref      : 'ref....',
        selector : 'selector....'
    }],
```

And then when I click a button I execute a function

```
      init: function() {
              this.control({                
        'selector' : {
            click : this.menu1
        },
        'selector' : {
            click : this.menu2          
        },
        'selector' : {
            click : this.menu3
        }       
              });
        },
```

Then in each function I just show/hide containers (same logic for all)

```
      menu1 : function(){
        this.getConatiner1().show();        
        this.getContainer2().hide();    
        this.getContainer3().hide();
     },
```

Everything works fine but the problem is how to handle this behavior if I have 100 conatiners (for any reason, does not matter).

How can I show/hide containers dynamically without repeating too many lines of code for manually hide/show containers?

I have tried to assign all selectors to an array something like

```
            var selectors = ['getContainer1','getContainer2',...]
```

and then just using a for loop to hide all of them and just show the correct one.

```
          for(allselectors){
            eval('selector.hide()');
          }
          selectedContainer.show();
```

Something like this seems to work, but I prefer to avoid eval. Any suggestions for this kind of logic?

Comment: Just a comment about your creation of items, you should really be doing `this.items =` in the constructor, not initComponent.

Comment: I always do it in `initComponent` . Seems interesting to research why this should be done in constructor. Maybe in another post

Comment: You know, I think it's something the entire Ext community struggles understanding, and I could be totally wrong.  However, looking at your code, it could definitely be configuration driven, and you'd definitely want that to be in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you didn't provide a Fiddle, so I don't have full code to work with.  What I'm thinking is that you add a [class](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-cfg-cls), say **containerPlaceHolder**, to each container, and then in your `menu1` method, you do something like `Ext.select('.containerPlaceHolder').hide();`, which will first return all of your HTML elements wrapped as an Ext object (specifically [Ext.dom.CompositeElement](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dom.CompositeElement)), and then give you access to the `hide` and `show` methods, which will hide or show all elements with that class name.

Comment: That's what I used to do with jQuery. I was originally thinking if there was another trick in extjs. I'll try it, thanks

Comment: Refs in controller will only retrieve the first component found as it does `down()`. A solution is to use `query()` to get all components (array) (`var report = this.getReport(), category = report.query('[cls=displayReport]'),`) from the view (main container) and then loop through all the components using `each` or `for`. `Ext.Array.each(category, function(construct, index) {  construct.hide();});`

Comment: Oh, well, I was under the assumption you were clicking a button that fired menu1 to hide the certain containers... if that's the case, then my code should work, and you shouldn't need their `refs` piece.

Comment: Consider the question is fully answered. Using class selector to trigger many fields at a time is the right way.